# Python, How to stop my code from showing position of my CSV file (No Panda)

Tags: python, csv

The code I have written gives me the desired output (takes data from csv file) but it shows the position of the function, which is something I do not want.

Here's my code:

```
# Functions
import sys
from collections import Counter
import csv

def NC(filename: list) -> str:
    print("----")
    print("Precondition: You must type the FULL name of the genre with the EXACT same capital/lower case lettering.")
    print("----")
    
    x = input("Enter the category of the books: ")
    
    category = []

    with open('Google_Books_Dataset.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        c = Counter(row['generes'] for row in csv_reader)
        result = print(c[x])
        category.append(result)
    return category

def CA(filename: list) -> str:
    print("----")
    print("Precondition: You must type the author's FULL name with the EXACT same capital/lower case lettering.")
    print("----")
    
    x = input("Enter the author's FULL name: ")
    
    author_name = []
    with open('Google_Books_Dataset.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file) 
        
        for row in csv_reader:
            result = {'author': row['author'], 'category': row['generes']}
            del result['author']
    
            if (row['author'] in x):
                author_name.append(result)
    print(list(author_name))
    return author_name

def CB(filename: list) -> str:
    print("----")
    print("Precondition: You must type the book's FULL name with the EXACT same capital/lower case lettering and special symbols (e.g. $ or *).")
    print("----")
    
    x = input("Enter the book's FULL name: ")
    
    book_name = []
    with open('Google_Books_Dataset.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file) 
            
        for row in csv_reader:
            result = {'title': row['title'], 'category': row['generes']}
            del result['title']
    
            if (row['title'] in x):
                book_name.append(result)
    print(list(book_name))
    return book_name

def Q(x: str) -> str:
    x = input("Enter quit: ")
    if (x == "quit"):
        print("END")
        sys.exit()    

# Command Line
print("Precondition: ALL commands must be of capital case.")
print("----")

x = input("Enter command: ")
List = ["NC", "CA", "CB", "Q"]

while (x != List): 

    if x == List[0]:
        name = []
        NC(name)
        print(NC)
            
    if x == List[1]:   
        name = []
        CA(name)
        print(CA)
            
    if x == List[2]:
        name = []
        CB(name)
        print(CB)
    
    if x == List[3]:
        name = []
        Q(name)
        print(Q)
    else:
        x = input("Enter command: ")
```

All of my functions always give back the function position, I don't know why.

For example, if I run my code and enter a command (Like NC), then my out would be:

```
Precondition: ALL commands must be of capital case.
----
Enter command: NC
----
Precondition: You must type the FULL name of the genre with the EXACT same capital/lower case lettering.
----
Enter the category of the books: Fiction
39
<function NC at 0x0000018E43A95670>
Enter command: ...
```

The **<function NC at 0x0000018E43A95670>** is not wanted. And all my other codes, other than the Quit command yield the position as well. How should I work around this?

Comment: Well, then remove the useless `print(NC)` and the like? What did you expect that to do anyway?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Remove the print(NC)? , at the bottom part? 

I am quite new to python and csv files so I have no idea.

Comment: @CZA, please check the updated answer I mentioned below. If it solved your problem please don't forget to upvote and accept it as a answer.

Comment: @CZA Not related to your question, but your `CA` and `CB` functions are identical except you swap "author" and "title". Delete one of those functions and make the function accept a string argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly printing function. Just it is printing an address. So kick out `print(NC)`.  I believe you are trying to print list of book names. So it is a list of strings you need to print.

If you really need to print book, replace `print(NC)`  with

```py
nc = NC(name)
print(nc)
```

Definitely it will work. Easy-Peasy ;)

Comment: thanks so much! I can't upvote because I am too new but it worked!

Comment: If you like it please accept it as answer.